# British Mathematical Olympiad - December 2003 - Round 1 - Question 1

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here's the question.

Solve the simultaneous equations
$$ab + c + d = 3$$
$$bc + d + a = 5$$
$$cd + a + b = 2$$
$$da + b + c = 6$$
where $a, b, c, d$ are real numbers.

Obviously there's a lot of ways to look at this, but I always find myselfat a dead end; either ending up with what I started with or getting a complicated mess. Is there a systematic way to approach this or is there just a niche technique required to answer this specific question? Also, is there a way of knowing before whether going through a method is going to provide new information of if I'm going to end up with something like $a=a$?

Comment: @RobertZ Cheers, btw how do you find these, I really couldn't find it

Comment: Use https://approach0.xyz/search/